# Acceder a los registros a través de una tabla intermedia - Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image]

Tengo una tabla "tickets", necesito traer con el ticket, los mensajes con sus respectivos archivos que se encuentran en otra tabla. A los mensajes, accedo con el método with, pero no he logrado traer los archivos.

Modelo Ticket

```
class Ticket extends Model { 

  public function messages()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(TicketMessage::class);
  }

  public function files()
  {
     return $this->messages->hasMany(TicketFile::class);
  }

}
```

Modelo Mensajes

```
class TicketMessage extends Model{

  public function ticket()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
  }

  public function file()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(TicketFile::class);
  }

}
```

Modelo Archivos

```
class TicketFile extends Model{

  public function message()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(TicketMessage::class);
  }

}
```

Así traigo el ticket y sus relaciones

```
public function scopeShow($query){

  return $query
  ->with('messages')
  ->with('files');

}
```

El Error que recibo

```
message: "Call to undefined relationship [files] on model [App\\Models\\Ticket]."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este punto considero que la mejor opción para *alcanzar* los archivos asociados a cada ticket sería por medio de las [*relaciones anidadas*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading), entonces puedes proceder de esta manera:

1. Elimina del modelo `Ticket` el método:

   ```
   public function file()
   ```
2. Tu consulta debería entonces quedar como:

   ```
   Ticket::with('messages.file')->get();
   ```

   - Lo que pasamos como argumento son:

     - Método `messages` definido en `Ticket` (*relación directa*)
     - Método `file` definido en `TicketMessage` (*relación anidada*)
3. Por cierto si un *ticket message* tiene muchos *ticke files* como se observa en tu código entonces en el modelo `TicketFile` deberás:

Pasar de esto:

```
return $this->hasOne(TicketMessage::class);
```

A esto:

```
return $this->belongsTo(TicketMessage::class);
```